# Is there a way of thinking when solving for the unknown variables using the partial derivatives from the Lagrange function?

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

For example,

$L=5xy+8xz+3yz-λ(2xyz+1920)$

$L(x) = 5y+8z-2λyz=0$

$L(y) = 5x+3z-2λxz=0$

$L(z) = 8x+3y-2λxy=0$

$L(λ) = -2xyz+1920=0$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Is it $2xyz+1920$ or $-2xyz+1920$? $\lambda = 0$ is an obvious solution. The other one's in this question do not seem straightforward to work with.

Comment: Equations coming from the Lagrange function are often difficult or impossible to solve analytically except in the simplest cases (linear with the odd quadratic thrown in maybe).

Comment: Do you need the solution of the system? $$x= 6,y= 16,z= 10,\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{cases}
-2 \lambda  y z+5 y+8 z=0\\
-2 \lambda  x z+5 x+3 z=0\\
-2 \lambda  x y+8 x+3 y=0\\
1920-2 x y z=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda = \frac{5 y+8 z}{2 y z}\\
-2 \frac{5 y+8 z}{2 y z}  x z+5 x+3 z=0\\
-2 \frac{5 y+8 z}{2 y z}  x y+8 x+3 y=0\\
1920-2 x y z=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda = \frac{5 y+8 z}{2 y z}\\
-\frac{x (5 y+8 z)}{y}+5 x+3 z=0\to -z (8 x-3 y)=0 \\
-\frac{x (5 y+8 z)}{z}+8 x+3 y=0\to -y (5 x-3 z)=0\\
1920-2 x y z=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda = \frac{5 y+8 z}{2 y z}\\
y= \frac{8 x}{3}\\
z=\frac{5x}{3}\\
1920-2 x \frac{8 x}{3} \frac{5x}{3}=0\to x^3=216\to x=6\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda = \frac{1}{2 }\\
y= 16\\
z=10\\
x=6\\
\end{cases}
$$